# How to pass javascript variables from one html page to other html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, querystringparameter

I have the following code to pass variable from example1.html to example2.html , what will be the syntax in window.location.href to navigate to example2.html with username and keyword.

**example1.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var username = ($("#username").val());
    var keyword = ($("#keyword").val());

    $("#button1").click(function(){
         window.location.href = "http://localhost:2757/example2.html";
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass them by query string parameters you can do this:

```
window.location = "http://localhost:2757/example2.html?username=" + username + "&keyword=" + keyword;
```

Comment: dont forget to encode the ampersands in the URL, either with &amp; instead of &, or by using window.location = encodeURI(url);