# How to pass javascript object from one page to other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass javascript object from one page to other page so anyone can tell me how to do it?

Is that possible to do so using jQuery?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the one and another page - are they open concurrently? is there a link from one to the other? more details are necessary

Comment: I have a JavaScript object and when I reload the page then I can't access that object anymore so I want to preserve that object even after refreshing the page.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to pass javascript variables...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757372/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-one-html-page-to-other-html-page), [how to pass javascript variables..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732965/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-one-javascript-page-to-another-javascript-p), and [How can I pass a value from on...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267519/how-can-i-pass-a-value-from-one-html-page-to-another-using-javascript).

Comment: I am not talking about passing the simple variable here. It's about object like `browser object window`.

Comment: @Dipen: All objects are variables. There's no difference.

Comment: There is actually a difference when it comes to what the variables contain. A simple value like a number can be serialised as a string and sent between pages, while an object like `window` can't be serialised.

Comment: @Guffa: You are right I tried to serialized window object but it's not working. Is it possible to pass `window` object one page to other page?

Comment: @Dipen: That is only possible if they are open at the same time in separate windows/tabs, and one page has a reference to the other window.

Comment: Some examples using *url* and *web storage*: **[How to send variables from one file to another in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17309679/2247494)** and a complete answer here: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/30070207/2247494**

Answer (score 17):

### Few ways

1. **Server side postback**

   Have a POST form on your page and save your serialized object inside a hidden input then post it to the other page. You will be able to process that data on the server and most likely put it back somehow into the page. Either as javascript object or anything else.
2. **Client side URL examination**

   Make a GET request to your *other* page by attaching your serialized object to URL as:

   http://www.app.com/otherpage.xyz?MyObject=SerializedData

   That *other* page can then easily parse its URL and deserialize data using Javascript.
3. **What's in a `window.name` = local cross-page session**

   This is a special technique that's also used in a [special javascript library](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) that exposes `window.name` as a dictionary, so you can save many different objects into it and use it as local cross-page-session. It has some size limitations that may affect you, but check the linked page for that and test your browsers.
4. **HTML5 local storage**

   HTML5 has the ability of local storage that you can use exactly for these purposes. But using it heavily depends on your browser requirements. Modern browsers support it though and data can be restored even after restarting browsers or computers...
5. **Cookies**

   You can always use cookies but you may run into their limitations. These days cookies are not the best choice even though they have the ability to preserve data even longer than current window session.

### Javascript object serialization

You will of course have to use some sort of a (de)serializer on your client side in some of the upper cases. Deserializers are rather easy to find (jQuery already includes a great function `$.getJSON()`) and are most likely part of your current javascript library already (not to even mention `eval()`).

But for object to JSON string serialization I'd recommend [json2.js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) that's also recommended by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/). This library uses in-browser implemented JSON (de)serialization features if they exist or uses it's own implementation when they don't. Hence recommendation.

Comment: I loved the special tecnhique part, make programmers sound like wizards or ninjas

Comment: Nice answer +1!!. I wrote some examples using *url* and *web storage*: **[How to send variables from one file to another in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17309679/2247494)** and a complete answer can be found here: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/30070207/2247494**

Comment: option number 4, but i still cant figure how to store object. Indeed i use it to store primitive value like string and number.

Answer (score 5):

That is only possible if the pages exist at the same time, and one page is opened from the other so that you have a reference to the other pages windows object.

If you navigate from one page to another, they don't exist at the same time, so you can't communicate like that. You would have to serialise the object into a string that you can send along in the request, for example sending JSON in the query string.

There are different ways of persisting data, like in the query string, post data, cookies, window name or HTML5 local storage, but all those methods can only persist string values, not Javascript objects.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you thing is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to do, and you have a couple of options.

**Local Storage**

Can be added/eddited/removed at any stage and accessed across a domain. (doesn't work natively in ie6 and ie7 however there are work arounds for that)

**The Window Object**

I would put a massive cavet around this not being the best solution, it's not at all secure, so only use it for things that don't need to be kept private. `window.name = { "json" : "object"}` which is then available in the following page in the window.name property.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only way to pass a javascript object from one page to another is to serialize it into string and pass it in url. For example if you have object

```
var temp = { id: 1, value: 'test' }
```

you may want to use [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to serialize it and pass it in for example `http://mysite.com/?data=serialization`. Then after you load the page you need to deserialize it via for example `$.parseJSON()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your application uses sessions, you could serialize it (as per other answers) then POST it to the server where it is stored in a session variable. In the next page, you retrieve it from the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, normally all variables only exist in a scope that is unique to that page load.  They don't persist between different pages if there is a new page load.

The exceptions to this are

1. Cookies.
2. Local storage.

**Cookies** are truly cross-browser but are extremely limited in terms of size.  You shouldn't expect to be able to store more than 4kB of cookies for a page reliably; in fact you probably shouldn't be using any more than 1kB.  Cookie data slows down the loading of every page and other request, so it should be used sparingly.

There are various types of **local storage** available to Javascript, but the only practical cross-browser implementation of this is [HTML5 webstorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) which is implemented in all modern browsers (IE8+, FF, Chrome, Safari, etc), but is notably not implemented in IE6 or IE7, if that matters.

Both these approaches store a value in the user's browser which can be made to be persistent so that it can be written to and read from by pages from the same site, even between page views (and even, often, between browser sessions or computer reboots).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [library some time ago](https://github.com/viseztrance/perseverance), that can store most js objects to localstorage. For example instances of your prototype classes, with references to other objects, self references included. Bare in mind that IE support is lackluster.