# How can I pass time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 2 pages. On page 1 i have two values, one is string and one is datetime.
I want to pass that value to page 2 but i have problem, the string is passed but datetime is not passed. This is my code

```
time = jQuery('#timepicker_7').val();    
    var url = "test.aspx?name=" + encodeURIComponent(lObjSeat[0].Name) + "&technology=" + encodeURIComponent(time);
    window.location.href = url;
```

this is what's on page 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var queryString = new Array();
$(function () {
    if (queryString.length == 0) {
        if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
            var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                queryString[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    if (queryString["name"] != null) {
        var data = "<u>Values from QueryString</u><br /><br />";
        data += "<b>Name:</b> " + queryString["name"] + " <b>Technology:</b> " + queryString["technology"];
        $("#lblData").html(data);
    }
});
```

"name" is done. but "time" is not show. whats the problem ?

Comment: What do you see in the urlbar after redirection with `location.href`?

Comment: you may use `json.js` [use this link for ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7709353/2749470)

Comment: or use [this link for json usage](http://stackoverflow.com/a/87737/2749470)

Comment: @BhargavModi using json doesn't solve the problem of not being able to get the string from the url. It is still a string - just a diffferent format

Comment: If it was me I would have the server grab the params and put them into javascript variables

Comment: in urlbar show code of html