# How to get data from another url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

Here's the dilemma. I'm voting on these different reports on webpage #1 (http://www.blankmediagames.com/Trial/#start) and I'm trying to get a specific object called "data" from webpage #2 (http://www.blankmediagames.com/Trial/viewReport.php?id=1388499). However, when I use this code, it only returns the entire webpage.

```
var tempVar;
var reportPage = new XMLHttpRequest();
reportPage.open('GET', '/Trial/viewReport.php?id=1388499', true);
reportPage.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (reportPage.readyState === 4)  { 
   tempVar = (reportPage.responseText);
  }
};
reportPage.send(null);
```

I am trying to grab the object called "data" from webpage #2 and store it in another variable while I'm on webpage #1. Is there any way I can do this?

This is basically what is found in webpage #2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                data = {"ReportID":"1388499","Username":"FatJellyBean","ReportFile":"Report1386875","Reason":"Gamethrowing","Appeal":"","Submitted":"Jun. 10, 2018 12:41 pm","numReports":2,"players":[{"username":"TooEzJukedBaited","ign":"ImJester","role":"SerialKiller","slot":1},{"username":"RISTR1K","ign":"Covfefe","role":"Doctor","slot":2},{"username":"balintka0607","ign":"William Phips","role":"Retributionist","slot":3},{"username":"JohnGotti","ign":"Karl Marx","role":"Veteran","slot":4},{"username":"Konrad4123","ign":"Pepe","role":"Escort","slot":5},{"username":"Celerian","ign":"Jeff","role":"Jester","slot":6},{"username":"foxesfan9","ign":"dabbingisnotcool","role":"Executioner","slot":7},{"username":"FatJellyBean","ign":"ifyoudonthitsubm","role":"Medium","slot":8},{"username":"GalaxyUnivern","ign":"Eliza Macbeth","role":"Godfather","slot":9},{"username":"Davve27","ign":"Katana","role":"Investigator","slot":10},{"username":"GayBobFaggyPants","ign":"Sarah Bishop","role":"Godfather","slot":11},{"username":"holysilman","ign":"Lil Tay","role":"Sheriff","slot":12},{"username":"pingvingen","ign":"Garfunkle","role":"Lookout","slot":13},{"username":"fefecute","ign":"Fefecute","role":"Framer","slot":14},{"username":"Frogers98","ign":"James Russel","role":"Jailor","slot":15}]};
                Trial.populateFilter(data);
                $
                                $('.reportedPlayer').html($('#FatJellyBean').next().html());
                $('#highlighter').show();
            });
            function highlight(elem,start,end)
            {
                var el=elem[0];
                var eln= (el.children.length > 0) ? el.lastChild : el.childNodes[0];
                var range=document.createRange();
                var sel=window.getSelection();
                start = (typeof start != 'undefined') ? start : 0;
                end = (typeof end != 'undefined') ? end : el.innerHTML.length;
                if(el.children.length > 0) start = end = 0;
                range.setStart(eln,start);
                range.setEnd(eln,end);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
                el.focus();
            }
        </script>
...
</html>
```

Comment: where do you see this data object on page #2?  Your best bet would be to use a json endpoint instead of hitting a full page, but if it's contained in a certain element, there are tricks to extracting data...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to transfer one object to another page, but not through the method you are trying.

There are a few hacks where you can use the url params: [How to pass javascript variables from one html page to other html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757372/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-one-html-page-to-other-html-page)

However it's more recommended to build endpoints and an API to pass information around. This sort of architecture involves more work but solves your exact problem: [How to pass javascript object from one page to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709289/how-to-pass-javascript-object-from-one-page-to-other)

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents data from being returned from other domains, including subdomains. You could try using [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), however.

Comment: You're not wrong, but the Same Origin Policy doesn't apply here because @Lord Nazo is getting data from the same domain. (e.g. blankmediagames.com)

Comment: Ah, you are correct, I read the URL's as subdomains for some reason